# search replace using Apache spark java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

**Problem Statement:**

We need to replace the Synonyms of the words in a row with its equivalent words (from large collection of synonym list ~40000+ Key Value pairs) on a large dataset(50000 rows).

**Example:**
    Input

```
Allen jeevi pramod Allen Armstrong
sandesh Armstrong jeevi
harsha Nischay DeWALT
```

**Synonym list (key value pair)**
//We have 40000 entries

```
Key         |   Value 
------------------------------------
Allen       |   Apex Tool Group
Armstrong   |   Columbus McKinnon
DeWALT      |   StanleyBlack
```

Above Synonym list has to be used on the Input and the Output should be as shown in the below format.

```
Expected Output

Apex Tool Group jeevi pramod Apex Tool Group Columbus McKinnon
sandesh Columbus McKinnon jeevi
harsha Nischay StanleyBlack
```

We have tried with 3 approaches all of them has its own limitations

**Approach 1**

*Using UDF*

```
    public void test () {
            List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create(0, "Allen jeevi pramod Allen Armstrong"),
            RowFactory.create(1, "sandesh Armstrong jeevi"),
            RowFactory.create(2, "harsha Nischay DeWALT")
       );

        StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
            new StructField("label", DataTypes.IntegerType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()) 
       });
        Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

        List<Row> data2 = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create("Allen", "Apex Tool Group"),
            RowFactory.create("Armstrong","Columbus McKinnon"),
            RowFactory.create("DeWALT","StanleyBlack")
        );

        StructType schema2 = new StructType(new StructField[] {
            new StructField("label2", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("sentence2", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()) 
        });
        Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema2);

        UDF2<String, String, Boolean> contains = new UDF2<String, String, Boolean>() 
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -5239951370238629896L;

            @Override
            public Boolean call(String t1, String t2) throws Exception {
                return t1.contains(t2);
            }
        };
        spark.udf().register("contains", contains, DataTypes.BooleanType);

        UDF3<String, String, String, String> replaceWithTerm = new UDF3<String, 
        String, String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -2882956931420910207L;

        @Override
        public String call(String t1, String t2, String t3) throws Exception {
            return t1.replaceAll(t2, t3);
        }
    };

    spark.udf().register("replaceWithTerm", replaceWithTerm, DataTypes.StringType);

Dataset<Row> joined = sentenceDataFrame.join(sentenceDataFrame2, callUDF("contains", sentenceDataFrame.col("sentence"), sentenceDataFrame2.col("label2")))
                                       .withColumn("sentence_replaced", callUDF("replaceWithTerm", sentenceDataFrame.col("sentence"), sentenceDataFrame2.col("label2"), sentenceDataFrame2.col("sentence2")))
                                       .select(col("sentence_replaced"));

joined.show(false);
}
```

`

```
Input
    Allen jeevi pramod Allen Armstrong
    sandesh Armstrong jeevi
    harsha Nischay DeWALT

Expected Output
    Apex Tool Group jeevi pramod Apex Tool Group Columbus McKinnon
    sandesh Columbus McKinnon jeevi
    harsha Nischay StanleyBlack

Actual Output
    Apex Tool Group jeevi pramod Apex Tool Group Armstrong
    Allen jeevi pramod Allen Columbus McKinnon
    sandesh Columbus McKinnon jeevi
    harsha Nischay StanleyBlack
```

*Issue with approach 1, if there are multiple synonym keys in the input dataset, that many rows are getting created as shown in the above example output. 
Expected only one row with all the replacement*

**Approach 2.**
Using ImmutableMap with replace function: Here we kept key and values pair in hashmap within ImmutableMap function, we called replace function to replace all the things
 but if a row contains multiple keys then it ignores complete row without replacing single key…

```
try {

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("JavaTokenizerExample").getOrCreate();

        HashMap<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
        options.put("header", "true");
        Dataset<Row> dataFileContent = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", options);
        dataFileContent=dataFileContent.withColumn("ManufacturerSource", regexp_replace(col("ManufacturerSource"),"[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s+]",""));
        dataFileContent= dataFileContent.na().replace("ManufacturerSource",ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
            .put("Allen", "Apex Tool Group"),
            .put("Armstrong","Columbus McKinnon"),
            .put("DeWALT","StanleyBlack")
            //Here we have 40000 entries
            .build()

          );
          dataFileContent.show(10,false);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the sample code and output:

```
Input
    Allen jeevi pramod Allen Armstrong
    sandesh Armstrong jeevi
    harsha Nischay DeWALT

Expected Output
    Apex Tool Group jeevi pramod Apex Tool Group Columbus McKinnon
    sandesh Columbus McKinnon jeevi
    harsha Nischay StanleyBlack

Actual Output
    Allen jeevi pramod Allen Armstrong
    sandesh Columbus McKinnon jeevi
    harsha Nischay StanleyBlack
```

**Approach 3**

*Using replace all within UDF*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("JoinFunctions").setMaster("local[*]"));
          SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
          SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("StringSimiliarityExample").getOrCreate();


            Dataset<Row> sourceFileContent = sqlContext.read()
                        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                        .option("header", "true")
                        .load("source100.csv");
            sourceFileContent.show(false);

        StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
        new StructField("label", DataTypes.IntegerType, false,
                Metadata.empty()),
        new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false,
                Metadata.empty()) });
        Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);
        UDF1 mode = new UDF1<String, String>() {
            public String call(final String types) throws Exception {
                return types.replaceAll("Allen", "Apex Tool Group")
                .replaceAll("Armstrong","Columbus McKinnon")
                .replaceAll("DeWALT","StanleyBlack")
                //40000 more entries.....
            }
        };

        sqlContext.udf().register("mode", mode, DataTypes.StringType);

        sentenceDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("people");
        Dataset<Row> newDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT mode(sentence), label FROM people").withColumnRenamed("UDF(sentence)", "sentence");
        newDF.show(false);
    }
```

**Output**
Stackoverflow exception.

Here, we are getting stackoverflow exception. Because it resembles recursive function call.

Kindly, let us know if there are any other innovative approaches that can help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Neither will work, since you always have the issue of substring matches. For example:

- ABC -> DE
- ABCDE -> ABC

With text "ABCDEF HIJ KLM" what will the output be? It should be the same as the input, but your approach will at best output "DEDEF HIJ KLM" and at worst you will do a double replacement and get "DEF HIJ KLM". Either case is incorrect.

You could improve this by adding boundaries to replacements, perhaps using regex. A better way however would be to first tokenize your input correctly, apply token replacement (which can be exact match), and then un-tokenize back to original format. This may be as simple as splitting by space, but you should give proper though as to what token boundaries may exist. (Stops, hyphens, etc).

Comment: Some of the aspect what you have raised are correct. like double replacement, but we have thought couple of approaches.   

1. All the substring matches to keep in top 

2. Add space before and after keys.
But this is the the core issue which are facing. Issue is when we are having large datasets.

Comment: If you tokenize it will never be an issue

Comment: Tokenization wont solve the issue, the core issue we are facing here is in the number of records of synonym list which should be used to do replacement, for small number of synonym list(key value pair) like 400 records it works for larger set like 40000 it fails.